# Backbone Route is not called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a working app using Backbone 0.5.3, which is no longer working using backbone 0.9.2.

I identified that Router.navigate() doesn't call my route for some reason.

Here's my Router:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '/mypage': 'mypage', 
    },

    mypage: function() { 
      // show page ...
   }
});
```

Calling the route manually like so works fine:

```
Router.mypage()
```

I also tried to overwrite backbone's .navigate method to debug my app ...

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '/mypage': 'mypage', 
    },

    navigate: function(fragment, options) {
      console.log("navigate called");
      Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
    },

    mypage: function() { 
      // show page ...
   }
});
```

... it seems that .navigate is called but ...

```
Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
```

... just doesn't call the route.

I'm using PushState, here's my initial call:

```
Backbone.history.start({ 
  root: '/',
  pushState: true,
  silent: true
});
```

Already tried it without the root and silent parameters - no success.

**Again: This works using Backbone 0.5.3.**

Thanks to everyone leaving a reply!

Achim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend):

> **extend** `Backbone.Router.extend(properties, [classProperties])`
>
> Get started by creating a custom router class. [...] Note that you'll want to avoid using a leading slash in your route definitions:

I'm guessing that you simply need to remove the leading slashes from your `routes`, for example:

```
routes: {
  'mypage': 'mypage', 
},
```

Comment: Hi @mu is too short,

thank you, I checked this already. the route isn't found with and without a leading and/or trailing slash.

Calling App.Router.mypage() works fine, so it must be something about route matching.

Comment: Whoops! You're right, just double-checked my routes and this fixes it!

Btw: The new behaviour about leading slashes in routes is mentioned in backbone's changelog for version 0.9
[http://backbonejs.org/#changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)

Comment: @Achim: Thanks for checking the changelog.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the trigger option for the navigate method, e.g:

`Router.navigate("/mypath", {trigger: true})`

Comment: Hi @Erez Rabih,
yes, I tried it with true + false.

On the console ...

`App.Router.navigate;`

... returns the following:

`function (fragment, options) {
  Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
}`

... while ...

`App.Router.navigate("/mypage", {trigger: false});`

... returns "undefined".

Comment: **This is not about using Backbone in general.** 

My App works fine using backbone 0.5.3 - there must be some change about url matching in backbone 0.9.2

Answer (score 0):

You must create instance of Router.

```
var router = new Router();
router.navigate(...);
```

Comment: Hi SoWA,

This is not the complete script, of course I instanciate the Router with

`App.Router = new Router;`

Having skipped this, the example wouldn't have worked in Backbone 0.5.3 either.